# Trouble installing ubuntu 22.04 LTS ("Jammy")

Tags: mongodb

So I've been having this problem for months. Originally I realized that 22.04 didn't have an official pkg and needed patchy solutions to fix, that didn't end up working for me, but now that they do it still keeps core dumping on me. I thought it might be my cpu architecture, so instead of installing through the terminal I tried to dpkg the mongodb-org-server_6.0.5_amd64.deb pkg directly here are my system specs

---

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64

Host: VirtualBox 1.2

Kernel: 5.19.0-35-generic

Uptime: 4 hours, 51 mins

Packages: 1978 (dpkg), 20 (snap)

Shell: bash 5.1.16

Resolution: 1920x1080

DE: GNOME 42.5

WM: Mutter

WM Theme: Yaru-purple-dark

Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3]

Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]

Terminal: gnome-terminal

CPU: 12th Gen Intel i7-12700

GPU: 00:02.0 VMware SVGA II Adapter

Memory: 3518MiB / 9729MiB

---

[image: System Spec]

Here's my journalctl logs

---

mongod.service.main process exited with core dump

---

[image: Journalctl -u]

Mongodb has the correct permissions but for some reason the logs don't show up in /var/log/mongodb The folder exists but is completely empty. var/lib/mongodb is also empty

[image: LOG EMPTY]

It's not my .conf file either, the paths are correct

[image: conf file]

I've tried daemon reloading, restarting, reinstalling, repairing, chatgpt. I've read through articles, and community posts, and stack overflow before posting. Thank you for your time

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Try to start it manually, e.g. `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` What is the output?

Comment: It exits with a core dump and asks to send error to OS